# Facebook SDk for Javascript isn't loading

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <header>
    </header>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.9'
        });
        FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>
    <div
      class="fb-like"
      data-share="true"
      data-width="450"
      data-show-faces="true">
    </div>

    </body>
```

I copied this code snippet directly from the facebook developer website with the right app ID, yet nothing appears, and whenever I try using FB.login(), I have a "FB not defined" error.
How am I wrong here ?

Comment: Try loading the SDK first.  Also, are you testing the code on a server?

Comment: Yep, if you can consider my computer a server. I'm using Node. Also, if loading the SDK first means putting the anonymous function on top, then no, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you'll find Facebook is expecting the request from a domain.

Comment: Hmm... Ain't Javascript supposed to query from the client side ?

Comment: Yes, but Facebook needs to decide to respond with the SDK

Comment: Will a no-ip address be enough ?

Comment: please open the browser console and check out warnings and errors. make sure you are using this code on a server, not just by opening the file from the file system.

Comment: I'm using Node, I uploaded the files on Heroku, and I still got this error :

C:\Users\Schrute\Desktop\amadou\node_modules\react-error-overlay\lib\effects\proxyConsole.js:56 ./src/index.js
  Line 2:  'FB' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 8:  'FB' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.